# Como converter notação científica para string com número completo

Tags: php, funções, conversão, cast

Que função do php devo utilizar para fazer esse tipo de conversão?

> **Converter: 1.3388383658903E+18 para: 1338838365890273563**

Tentei isso, mas não deu certo:

```
echo sprintf(sprintf('%%.%df', 0), '1.3388383658903E+18');
```

E isso também:

```
echo rtrim(sprintf('%.0F', $value), '0');
```

> editado até aqui para explicar melhor o problema:

Veja esse exemplo com `serialize`:

```
$a = array('valor' => 1338838365890273563);
$serializado = serialize($a);
```

Como corrigir isso quando for fazer `unserialize($serializado)`?

[**Exemplo no ideone**](http://ideone.com/nuXE9R)

Comment: Assim não funciona `$notation = 1.3388383658903E+18;
printf('%.0F', $notation);` ?

Comment: Tentou com número, em vez de string?

Comment: eu não entendi porque usou dois `sprintf(sprintf`?

Comment: Eu não entendi foi nada, eu peguei de um exemplo... que não deu certo.

Comment: Mas então esse código não tem sentido algum `sprintf(sprintf('%%.%df', 0), '1.3388383658903E+18');`, ao menos pra mim. Não faz sentido fazer um sprintf de 0 e depois usar o resultado para outro sprintf, seria melhor ter lido o minimo da documentação, não concorda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sobre a precisão numérica:

A pergunta pede algo que não é possível, converter `1.3388383658903E+18` para `1338838365890273563`.

A notação `1.3388383658903E+18` só tem precisão para as casas que realmente estão legíveis na string.

Se precisa do valor original, converta para string **antes** do `serialize`:

```
$a = array('valor' => '1338838365890273563' );
$serializado = serialize($a);
```

Veja as aspas no valor. Note que mesmo que no seu código esteja escrito o valor literal:

```
$valor = 1338838365890273563;
```

internamente o PHP vai guardar só o que cabe no float. Assim, é essencial que você trate os dados como *string* durante toda a "vida" do script.

Se precisar de maior capacidade numérica, pode usar a bc_math e GMP, mas no seu caso provavelmente *strings* são uma melhor solução. Mais detalhes no manual do PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php

### Sobre a exibição de notação científica:

Basta isso:

```
echo sprintf( '%f', 1.3388383658903E+18 );
```

Ou isso, claro:

```
$numero = '1.3388383658903E+18'; // o ideal mesmo é sem aspas
echo sprintf( '%f', $numero );
```

Se preferir sem os decimais:

```
echo sprintf( '%.0f', 1.3388383658903E+18 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KCrQ8E)**.

#### Se for só pra mostrar na tela:

Aí nem precisa do echo, basta usar `printf` no lugar do `sprintf`:

```
printf( '%.0f', 1.3388383658903E+18 );
```

Mantive o `sprintf` no exemplo original, pois normalmente é o que vai ser usado se for guardar o valor numa string, ou concatenar com alguma outra coisa.

### Observações:

- Não podemos usar `%d`, pois a capacidade de inteiros é estourada;
- o uso do `.0` antes do `f` serve para dizer que queremos zero casas decimais;
- não tem necessidade de aspas no valor, pois o formato `nE+n` já é entendido como número pela linguagem naturalmente. Mas veja no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/JMcHRF) que o problema não é esse, pois o PHP faz o *cast* de qualquer forma.
- não faz diferença no nosso caso, mas cuidado, pois `%f` e `%F` são coisas diferentes. Ambos são float, mas um deles é `locale-aware` (o que muda o sinal dos decimais de acordo com a região).

Answer (score 0):

Só para constar aqui, existe uma forma de resolver esse serialize, que é passando o número para string, isso ninguém pensou:

```
$a = array('valor' => (string) 1338838365890273563);
$serializado = serialize($a);

echo $serializado;
echo "\n-------------------------\n";
var_dump(unserialize($serializado));
```

[E**xemplo utilizando função**](http://ideone.com/f27ttL)

Answer (score -1):

```
$notation = 1.3388383658903E+18;


//Com decimais(8) só alterar conforme for necessario.

echo "Decimal: " . number_format($notation ,8);

//Sem decimais(bem simples apenas adicione 1 e depois adicione a quantidade de zeros que possui na versão decimal)

echo "Normal: " . number_format($notation * 100000000);
```

Comment: Se você multiplicar o valor por 100000000 você está alterando o valor.

Comment: Não,porque segue um principio matemático :) ex: vai multiplicar por um e adicionar os zeros. igual 10 x 10 = 100 (se você for ver o 0 de um vem para o outro) a mesma coisa se repete na notação,pode fazer a o teste :) eu testei com frações de criptomoedas e funcionou por isso postei aqui

Comment: A questão é que o valor `$notation * 100000000` será 1.3388383658903E+26, com ordem de grandeza 26, não 18 como é o número original.

Comment: bom eu testei aqui e foi de boa,até porque quando coloca a notação dentro da number_format ele  já muda para a numeração original a parte de multiplicar é somente para valores pequenos ex: 0.00000001 <- em apis de criptomoedas o Site responde em notação,colocando daquela forma e multiplicando fica no valor normal

Answer (score -7):

Você somar a notação cientifica mais um (1) que ele irá retornar o número em double/float.

Ex.:

```
$notation = "1.3388383658903E+18";
echo $notation + 1;
```

Isso ocorre porque o PHP é uma linguagem com tipagem fraca.